# How to create a new column in a dataframe, with either 1 or 0 based on percentage of results in previous columns?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I have a data frame with 144 rows and 48 columns. It contains results from various prediction models as either 1 or 0. I want to go through a row, find the percentage of 1's in that row and add a new column with either 1 if the percentage is greater than 80, else 0.

I know how to do this in excel with **if** and **countif/count%**, but here I don't really know how to do it. I hope I provided enough info, I am sorry if I did not. Thank you very much for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the percentage of 1's in each row with:

```
df['percentage'] = df.mean(axis=1)
```

Then to create your new binary column you can use `np.where`:

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['percentage'] > 0.8, 1, 0)
```

This works the same way as the excel `=IF` (condition, value if true, value if false).

Example with dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'var1':[0,0,1],'var2':[0,1,1], 'var3':[1,1,1]})
df['percentage'] = df.mean(axis=1)
df['new'] = np.where(df['percentage'] > 0.8, 1, 0)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   var1  var2  var3  percentage  new
0     0     0     1    0.333333    0
1     0     1     1    0.666667    0
2     1     1     1    1.000000    1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use .sum and cast to int in you prefer it over boolean. To set the value of the column `lots_of_ones` to 1 if the percentage of 1s on the other columns is bigger than a threshold you can do:

```
import pandas as pd

threshold = 0.8
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,0,0],[0,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1]])
df["lots_of_ones"] = (df.sum(axis=1) / df.columns.shape[0] > threshold).astype(int)
```

Result

```
>>> df
   0  1  2  3  lots_of_ones
0  0  0  0  0             0
1  0  1  1  1             0
2  1  1  1  1             1
```